# postgresql -select n number of rows if there are n number of unflagged rows available and update the flag

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres which is being constantly updated.I want to select first 5 rows if there are 5 rows available and update the flag associated with it.

```
At first the table looks like this
    id   name   flag
    11    ss     -
    22    aa     -
    12    bb     -
    13    cc     -
    14    dd     -
    23    ab     -
    24    cd     -
    25    ee     -
```

After the first selection of 5 rows, the table should be like the following

```
    id   name   flag
    11    ss     Y
    22    aa     Y
    12    bb     Y
    13    cc     Y
    14    dd     Y
    23    ab     -
    24    cd     -
    25    ee     -
```

And the next select shouldn't happen because there aren't exactly 5 rows left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window function can be used to count all rows in result set. Try something like

```
WITH unflagged AS (
    SELECT id FROM (
       SELECT id, count(*) over() AS cnt
       FROM your_table
       WHERE flag IS NULL
    ) WHERE cnt >= 5
    LIMIT 5
)
UPDATE your_table SET flag = Y
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM unflagged)
```

Comment: The above is setting the cnt as 8(as there are only 8 rows) where I want exactly the first 5 rows where flag is null

Comment: You are right, I've missed the limit. The query is just to give the idea how the count of records in result set can be get and filter on.